# Show that $I(X\cap Y)=\sqrt{I(X) + I(Y)}$ where $X,Y$ are varieties in $\mathbb{C}^n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

I want to show that $I(X\cap Y)=\sqrt{I(X) + I(Y)}$ where $X,Y$ are varieties in $\mathbb{C}^n$. All I know is the basic definition of a variety and its corresponding ideal.

I know that $X \cap Y \subset X$ so $I(X)\subset I(X \cap Y)$ and similarly $I(Y)\subset I(X \cap Y)$, implying $I(X)+I(Y)\subset I(X \cap Y)$. But then I have no idea where the radical comes in, or how to prove the other direction; I know that the statement is false without the radical having seen a counterexample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your argument can be made to work, but there's an easier way:

Recall $I(V(\mathfrak{a})) = \sqrt{\mathfrak{a}}$ for any ideal $\mathfrak{a}$
(this is the nullstellensatz).

Now if we can show $X \cap Y = V(I(X) + I(Y))$, we can prove the claim by hitting both sides with $I$:

$$I(X \cap Y) = I(V(I(X) + I(Y))) = \sqrt{I(X) + I(Y)}$$

But if we have a point $p \in X \cap Y$, we know that $p$ satisfies all the polynomials $\{ f_i \}$ defining $X$, as well as all the polynomials $\{ g_j \}$ defining $Y$. So $p$ must *also* satisfy $\{ f_i + g_j \}$, and so $p \in V(I(X)+I(Y))$.

Conversely, if $p$ satisfies $\{ f_i + g_j ~|~ f_i \in I(X), g_j \in I(Y) \}$ then $p$ also satisfies each $f_i$ and $g_j$ individually, since $0 \in I(X)$ and $0 \in I(Y)$.

This is the basic idea, but you should flesh it out and make sure you understand each step.

---

I hope this helps ^_^